# C# Timer not resetting from one click to another

Tags: c#, timer

I need to store the piano duration with Ticks as so then make the music note show according to that duration (Music players would know).

I'm using an interval of 100, but for some testing I used it at 1000.

The problem is this. When I'm invoking the method (I'm taking the **1000 millisecond interval one**) the timer starts.. if I DO NOT manage to get the 1000 milliseconds it shows Duration 0: but then if I do for example 2 seconds, it shows 3 seconds, if I try to press it for another second (a different key) it would show 4 seconds instead of 1.

It's like it keeps on recurring. Same happened with the 100 interval one. It went mad. sometimes 40 sometimes 23 and so on. Any idea how to fix (resetting the timer)

**N.B I'm using System.Windows.Forms.Timer** as library

part of a method which invokes the methods further below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    WhiteKey wk = new WhiteKey(wKeys[i], wPos[i]-35,0); //create a new white Key with [i] Pitch, at that x position and at y =0 position
    wk.MouseDown += onRightClick; //holds the Duration on Right Click
    wk.MouseUp += onMouseUp;
    wk.Click += new EventHandler(KeyClick); //Go to KeyClick Method whenever a key is pressed
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(wk); //Give it control (to play and edit)
}
```

Methods controlling the time

```
private void onRightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{        
    wk = sender as WhiteKey;
    duration = 0;
    t1.Enabled = true;
    t1.Tick += timeTick;
    t1.Interval = 100; 
}

private void timeTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    duration++;
}

private void onMouseUp (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    t1.Enabled = false;
    String time = "Key: " + pitch + "\nDuration: " +duration ; //Test purposes to see if timer works
    MessageBox.Show(time);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to measure time, don't use Timer, use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can find [C# Stopwatch Exmples at dotnetpearls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch).

In abstract this is what you would want to do is something like this:

```
private void onRightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
}

private void onMouseUp (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    stopwatch.Stop();
    String msg = "Duration in seconds: " + (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0).ToString("0.00");
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

Note: you may want to change the units or the string format.

---

Notes on using timer:

1) System.Windows.Forms.Timer uses the message loop of your window, this means that it may get delayed because the window is busy handling other events (such as click). For a better behaviour use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

2) If using System.Windows.Forms.Timer don't set the Tick event handler each click. The event handler will execute once for each time you add it.

That is:

```
private void onRightClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{        
    wk = sender as WhiteKey;
    duration = 0;
    t1.Enabled = true;
    //t1.Tick += timeTick; you should add this only once not each click
    t1.Interval = 100;
}
```

3) If you use System.Threading.Timer you may want to make the variable `duration` `volatile`.

Comment: I  tried the STOPWATCH, worked like a charm Thank you. I'll see also the 2nd method of The Timer. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Another thing. the Windows.Timers.TIMER - how does it handle TICKS since it actually doesn't have it in it's library?

Comment: @DodoSerebro Timer.Tick is an event. Internally Timer it stores a list of the method it has to call each "tick". When you say `t1.Tick += timeTick` you are saying: "I want you to call timeTick each time the event Tick fires". Now, the Tick event works by telling the OS to issue a message at a given interval (In windows it is a WM_TIMER, see [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx)), each time the window gets this message it will run a dedicated function that is handled by the Timer object, that in turn will call all the methods in his list.

Answer (score 1):

```
t1.Tick += timeTick;
```

By the way in your code sample you subscribe to the 'Tick' timer event each time on Right mouse click.
So if you click 2 times the

```
private void timeTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

method will be called twice, and 'duration++' will be executed twice. Your event subscription code should be executed only once for the timer.
P.S. If you need to measure duration, Timer is not the best way to do it.

Comment: So in this case, If I am to use the t1.Tick += time Tick.. where should it be exactly? Outside the onRightClick method?

Comment: Thank you, will try it just in case though Stopwatch is working perfectly :) Thanks again for your help!